# Table column split issue in XSL

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

[image][image]I am pullng my hair to find the error in this code, my table column is cutting into two line but I want to display the column data in single line. Same table is used for displaying data in other senario and works fine. I belive the column data "Data Not Available" is pulling the content into 2 lines, anyinput wil be a great help.

```
<table style="width=73%;table-layout:auto" border="0"  white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="no-wrap" white-space="nowrap">
<xsl:for-each select="webpage/param">    
  <tr>
    <xsl:if test="@type !='i'">  
    <td class="rowBlue">
    <xsl:if test="@indent !=''">  

        <!-- Generate the appropriate number of indentation -->
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="@indent"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="(//*)[position()&lt;=$count]">
            <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>   

    </xsl:if>           
    <xsl:choose>            
        <xsl:when test="@isBold='1'">
            <strong><span id="{position()-1}{@nameStrID}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></span></strong>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>  
            <span id="{position()-1}{@nameStrID}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></span>
        </xsl:otherwise>    
    </xsl:choose>  
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>        
    </td>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Is a BR tag being inserted after "Data Not"? You could try adding the CSS "white-space:nowrap;" to the TD and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using style

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;" id="{position()-1}{@nameStrID}">  
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></span>
```

Comment: Sorry to ask this basic question, which area I have to try this

Comment: Style is something like class in C++ right, Can I give <style> above  // <table style

Comment: Thanks my fried it works for first column " channel X" but "Data Not Available" is still in 2 lines

Comment: edited to get more clear. similarly u can use both the places.

Comment: I would suggest to use html tables then u wont get these glitches

Comment: Tried both place but "Data Not Available" not working and "channel X" have indent that too gone.

Comment: try using <td> with wrap attrib instead of span

Comment: Can you please little more ellabrate, how to use with <td>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19953/discussion-between-sijith-and-vels4j)